# Telerik MVC Extensions: Grid: During Ajax binding calls why is so much data posting back in the query string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using Ajax binding with the Grid and ran into a problem where ASP.NET MVC was throwing a *HttpRequestValidationException* when I attempted an operation on the grid that invoked the Ajax call (like sorting).

Using Fiddler I was able to determine my browser was attempting to post back my entire model in the query string and there were some characters that would have triggered ASP.NET's request validation.

I was able to work around this by simply adding

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

to my controller action.

I'm wondering **why was the grid sending back so much data?** And **is this a symptom of a bug in my code or Telerik's?**

Here is what I saw in Fiddler (note the extremely long query string, even though the HTTP verb is "POST").

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:52601/MyController/DatabindGrid?Items=System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection%601%5BPMyNamespace.Data.ViewEntities.Alert%5D&DetailsClientUrl=&GetJsonUrl=%2FMonitor%2FGetGridJson&ViewName=&CurrentItem=&PageTitle=My%20Web%20Page&CopyrightText=Copyright%20%26%23x00A9%3B%202004-2010%20My%20Company%20Corporation&BrowserCapabilities=&OemName=&UiVersion=20101123 HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://ipv4.fiddler:52601/MyController/MyAction
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: 127.0.0.1:52601
Content-Length: 56
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=bvgwuno4bounqio2werepkw4; .ASPXAUTH=612E18BB916F720D13A0F0D1695A86079B94DFE94A3BF5A9A8F19E35A37AE987282B7B684201C112CEC6081181E3D1C52C5517A66D9158E4CF83C1C3F523EE32FF783BD2E3B6E0A42A35E1874E63BA76C7735F9E8ABBA4E58BF61EB29DA03789E07A201A1BA9E7B85F941516ED7EA26E3E8E1E65D0836F39A109201E357EE97478D1A359B3FB4B4AD4C64A02A0CE7BBB39DC8FE1F73B179F284A14CF55D9C67D
page=1&size=10&orderBy=LocationName-asc&groupBy=&filter=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick,

I think you might be interested in this...

http://tv.telerik.com/watch/aspnet-mvc/video/building-a-responsive-site-with-mvc

very detailed and informative.

~AZee

Comment: Thanks! This is a good resource.  While not directly addressing my question it is giving me some leads for where I should look next for an answer.